# Fourier transform of a basic cos function.

Tags: fourier-transform

In a quest to recreate [this](https://twitter.com/haum72/status/962084253717721089) incredible effect, I’m trying to find $p^{-1}(x')$ where

$p(x') = \mathcal{F}^{-1}\{\mathcal{F}\{p_1\}(u)\mathcal{F}\{p_2\}(-u)\}$

and both p1 and p2 are the same basic periodic function:

p(x) = ½  + ½ cos x

**Context:** 
I’m trying to use the moiré effect as a tool for optical encryption. Using target image $I$, I want to generate two random-looking key images that when superimposed reveal $I$. Turns out, quite a bit of math is involved. 
I found [this](http://www.cv-foundation.org/openaccess/content_iccv_2013/papers/Tsai_Target-Driven_Moire_Pattern_2013_ICCV_paper.pdf) paper and have been following the steps. My math skills are limited, but I’ve been able to understand most of it. The gap in my knowledge concerns Fourier transform. I understand the concept thanks to videos like [this](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjmhNmn99biAhWBLVAKHYyIDAMQyCkwAHoECAkQBA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DspUNpyF58BY&usg=AOvVaw0uW8jOZg0TZLzGI_mQRQ5O), but I have no idea how to practically perform it. From what I understand, it actually seems senseless to take a Fourier transform of a simple cos function.

Other sources: 
- a French [blogpost](https://haum.org/premiers_moires.html) about manipulating moiré artifacts, by the same people who made that elephant gif.

Comment: The Fourier transform of $p$ gives three delta function terms, but $\delta^2$ is not defined (the product corresponds to the convolution, and $p * p$ is not well-defined even as a distribution).

Comment: So how can we figure out what they mean?
According to the linked paper, this formula is equivalent to $p_{k_1,k_2}(x') = \sum^{\infty}_{n=-\infty} c^{(1)}_{k_1n}c^{(2)}_{k_2n}e^{i2\pi x'}$ 

where $c^{(1)}_{j}$ and $c^{(2)}_{j}$ are Fourier coefficients of $p_1$ and $p_2$ at frequency $j$. (page 3, bottom left, equation (6)).

$k_1$ and $k_2$ are set to $1$ and $-1$ later in the paper.


They add that since $p_1$ and $p_2$ are periodic functions with periods $T = 1$, their Fourier coefficients are non-zero only when $j$ is an integer.

Comment: My suggestion is to consult Amidror's book that they cite.